# Noun similar to Nostalgic or Sentimental

Tags: nouns, terminology, vocabulary

Funny Example:

My older brothers used to love "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone" when they were young. Now they're older and it's clear that they enjoy the modern Harry Potter movies (Deathly Hallows) more. Yet they insist that the first Harry Potter movie is still the best because they are:

Sentimental?

Nostalgic?

????????

Is there a more accurate term to be used here?

Comment: *Nostalgia* is the noun from which *nostalgic* is derived; and it seems that's what you're pointing towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentimental does not fit, but **nostalgic** seems like what you are looking for.

> - nostalgia - "pleasure and sadness that is caused by remembering something from the past and wishing that you could experience it again" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgia)

Your elder brothers seem to be filled with nostalgia for the early Harry Potter movies.

Then again, "sentimental" does not mean remembering something from the past.

> - sentimental - "having, showing, or caused by emotion, especially tender or affectionate feeling" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentimental)